# How to send MAMP PHP errors to browser console

Tags: php, macos, google-chrome-devtools, mamp, google-chrome-console

Is there any way to redirect PHP errors from my php_error.log file to my browser's console? This would help catch errors much faster without constantly switching between Chrome, Brackets, and Console.app.

Comment: [Chrome Logger](https://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger) will allow you to log to the browser console. Although not automatically from the PHP error log. Another option might be to look into a way to tail a file from within Chrome or Brackets.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you want to see PHP Errors in Browser Consoles!

There is few ways to do that.

**Firefox:**
You can use extenstion called [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) which enable the logging and duping of information from your PHP application to the console.

**Chrome:**

Also with chrome there is "[ChromePHP](http://www.chromephp.com/)" available which you can use:

**Direct from PHP**
But this will not work for all the PHP errors, because its not realtime, since php sends all page at once it's finishing processing, Furthermore, if there is an error in php file, you an't get to see any of the logs even,

```
function console_log( $error) {
    $error_output= $error
    if ( is_array( $error_output) )
        $error_output = implode( ',', $error_output);

    echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $error_output . "' );    </script>";
}
```

**Using:**

```
console_log('error');
```